# Can I get my links back in Gmail for selecting threads instead of the new drop down?

Tags: gmail, user-interface

Gmail recently switched from links that would allow you to select multiple threads (read, unread, starred, none, etc.) to a drop down to do same:

[image: gmail select drop down]

I would like my links back (one less click). Is there a way to switch back to the old view?

Answer (score 1):

In the Labs tab of Settings in GMail, there is a Lab feature called "Mark as Read Button" which you can use to make that action work on multiple threads while it appears as a label.

Comment: useful! That saves a click. I still want my links back though...